# How to achieve Circular progress bar?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

[image]

I am currently working in my Android project in which i need the progress bar to be as shown .

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your layout xml file:

`<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

Is this what You meant?

Comment: No, i want the progress bar in the same way as shown in the image. I tried with custom progress bar too but no use.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try [this Circle Progress library](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)**

CircularProgress:

```
 <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
    android:id="@+id/circle_progress"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:circle_progress="20"/>
```

CircleProgress:

```
  <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
    android:id="@+id/circle_progress"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:circle_progress="20"/>
```

ArcProgress:

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
    android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
    android:background="#214193"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:arc_progress="55"
    custom:arc_bottom_text="MEMORY"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public class CustomAlertDia extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //crated new alert dialog
        Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(this);
        alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dia);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); //transperent background
        ImageView hero = (ImageView)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_progress);

        //setup rotate background effect
        RotateAnimation ro = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        ro.setDuration(1500);
        ro.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        ro.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

        hero.setAnimation(ro);

        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

You can take [this image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/13252376/15803867/d7a5a2a8-2aa7-11e6-92e9-c733518e768f.png) and check it